# How does pointer to pointer to function (**ppf)() differ from pointer to function (*pf)() in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I wondering if there is a difference between `int (**ppf)(int)` and `int (*pf)(int)` in C.

C has this wierd way of treating function pointers where a function automatically transforms into a pointer to function. That allows programmers to write really wierd stuff.

```
double (*pf)(double) = ***&*&***&*sin;
(******&*&*puts)("Hello, world!");
```

This is really strange and I do not see how it is useful.

Here are my question(s) about *pointer to pointer to function* in C.

Does `int (**ppf)(void)` have more levels of indirection than `int (*pf)(void)`?

Is there any case where using `(**ppf)()` is superior to `(*pf)()`?

**Are there any differences between them at all?**

Is even it possible to get a *pointer to pointer to function* in C?

Comment: How does a pointer to int differ from a pointer to pointer to int?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a difference in between `(**ppf)()` and `(*pf)()`. And pointer to pointer to a function exist in c.

```
void f();
void (*pf)() = f // or &f
void (**ppf)(e) = &pf;
```

Any one of the following function call can be used to call function `f`:
using `f`: `f(); ( &f)(); (*f)(); (**f)(); (***f)();`
using `pf`: `pf(); (*&pf)(); (*pf)(); (**pf)(); (***pf)();`
using `ppf`: `(*ppf)(); (********ppf)`

Answer (score 0):

They're different types. They are even different classes of types; C makes a distinction between *object pointers* and *function pointers*. Any function pointer can be assigned to any other function pointer (without a cast), which is not true for object pointers.

Obviously, `pf` is a function pointer. But a pointer to a function pointer is a pointer to an object, namely, to the function pointer.